# Using the command line "find | grep -wc" how do I return values that are greater than zero?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, grep, find

I downloaded a .htm file and typed this in

```
find . -iname "*.htm" | xargs grep -Ewcp 'sevenfold'
```

I am unsure what the –E does but I know –wcp is word count and path. A sample of what shows up it this.

```
./bible/bible/RecoveryVersion_htm/ZecN.htm:1
./bible/bible/RecoveryVersion_htm/ZecO.htm:0
./bible/bible/RecoveryVersion_htm/Zep.htm:0
./bible/bible/RecoveryVersion_htm/ZepN.htm:0
./bible/bible/RecoveryVersion_htm/ZepO.htm:0
```

This list is rather long with many zeros how to I narrow the search to only display the ones without zeros hits for the word ? Can I somehow put an if statement “if the value is 0 don’t display“ is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another invocation of `grep` to filter the results:

```
find . -iname "*.htm" | xargs grep -Ewcp 'sevenfold' | grep -v ':0$'
```